# Envío y Recepción de notificaciones Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

Tengo una aplicación tipo red social, en la que un usuario inicia sesión, y por medio de un botón manda notificaciones a otro usuario. Es la primera vez que uso notificaciones así que he estado investigando y encontré la forma de generar la notificación pero lo hace de forma local (es decir en la misma aplicación).

Lo hago por medio de este código:

```
//Create notification
        var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as
             NotificationManager;

        //Create an intent to show ui
        var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

        //Create the notification
        var notification = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.Icon, "Tienes notificación");
        //var notification = new Notification(Android.Resource.Drawable.SymActionEmail,title);

        //Auto cancel will remove the notification once the user touches it
        notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

        //Set the notification info
        //we use the pending intent, passing our ui intent over which will get called
        //when the notification is tapped.
        notification.SetLatestEventInfo(this,"Tienes nueva notificación", "Te ha enviado una solicitud de contacto", PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0));

        //Show the notification
        notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
```

Hay alguna forma de que esa misma notificación se le envíe al otro usuario? (Como en las notificaciones de facebook). Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Las notificaciones remotas se envían usando infraestructura del proveedor de tu sistema operativo:

- Android tiene GCM/Firebase
- iOS tiene APNS
- Windows tiene WNS

El concepto base es el mismo. Por cada combinación dispositivo/app, el servidor de notificaciones push (Firebase/APNS/WNS) genera un token que identifica esa instancia de la app corriendo en ese dispositivo. Mediante llamadas nativas puedes pedir el token y guardarlo para enviarlo a TU backend o servidor. Desde tu servidor puedes enviar las notificaciones haciendo peticiones al servidor de notificaciones push, indicando el o los tokens a los que quieres enviar notificaciones.

Para Xamarin Forms [existe un plugin de notificaciones push](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/PushNotificationPlugin) que te permite pedir el token de manera bien sencilla. La responsabilidad de guardar y usar el token es tuya, por lo que tendrás que crear un backend en PHP/ASP.NET/NodeJS o lo que quieras para recibir el token, guardarlo y usarlo para enviar notificaciones.

Para enviar notificaciones desde aplicaciones .NET yo uso [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) desde hace años y funciona muy bien.